# Angular get value from object based on other value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a **form.service.ts** with the array object below;

```
readonly userTypesOptions = [
    { value: 'ADMIN', text: 'Administrator' },
    { value: 'MEMBER', text: 'Member' },
    { value: 'GUEST', text: 'Guest' }
];

getUserTypes() {
    return this.userTypesOptions; 
}
```

and a **form.component.ts** with a variable:

`currentUser = 'ADMIN'`

I am looking to get the associated text value from the object above inside my HTML template. Sadly the code below does not work because I don't know how to get the the text based on the value.

**form.component.html**

```
{{ userTypesOptions[currentUser].text }}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to have `userTypesOptions` as an object instead of an array? Otherwise, you could use `.find`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Explosion Pills said

```
getValue(currentUSER){
   let option = this.userTypesOptions.find(opt => opt.value === currentUSER);
   return (option || {}).text;
}
```

or :

```
readonly userTypesOptions = {
    'ADMIN' :'Administrator',
    'MEMBER': 'Member' ,
    'GUEST':'Guest' 
}
```

and  access to it like this :

```
{{ userTypesOptions[currentUser]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to look up the option type by a value instead of a key.

in userTypesOptions, there is no key called 'ADMIN'. 'ADMIN' is a VALUE identified by the KEY 'value'.

What you could to is this:

```
readonly userTypesOptions = [
    { 'ADMIN': 'Administrator' },
    { 'MEMBER': 'Member' },
    { 'GUEST': 'Guest' }
];
```

Then whenever you accessed the item using the KEY 'ADMIN', you would get the VALUE 'Administrator'

```
{{ userTypesOptions[currentUser] }}  // <-- renders 'Adminisrator' when currentuser = 'ADMIN'
```

EDIT: I guess my answer was not quite right, you'd want to also convert the userTypesOptions to an object instead of an array, like so:

```
readonly userTypesOptions = {
    'ADMIN': 'Administrator',
    'MEMBER': 'Member',
    'GUEST': 'Guest'
};
```